# In jquery modal view idtab link is not working

Tags: jquery, tabs, modal-dialog

If I add idtab in main page it works fine. But when I add idtab in modal window, all the tab entries are showing and clicking on link doesn't work.

Its sample code I tested. Can you point me to what I am doing incorrectly here.

```
var str = $("<div id="divid" class="panel">' +
        '<div class="panelname"><span class="panellabel">Header</span></div>' +
            '<ul class="idTabs"><li><a href="#jquery">jQuery</a></li><li><a href="#official">Tabs 3</a></li></ul>' +
            '<div id="jquery">JQUERY TAB</div><div id="official">NEXT TAB</div>' +
        '</div>');

this.append(str);
    str.jqm({modal:true,overlay: 0});
    str.jqmShow();
    str.draggable();

    $('#divdiv').idTabs();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide a ton of detail, but it sounds like the problem you are having is that idtabs initializes the tabs in the main content area automatically when the page is finished loading, but since the idtabs don't yet exist in the modal window, they aren't automatically initialized.  I'm pretty sure this is the plugin you're referring to - http://www.sunsean.com/idTabs/ , and if that's the case, you simply need to call the initialization function on the tabs that get inserted into the modal window after the modal is opened.

```
$("."+idTabs).idTabs();
```

Comment: Brad, Thanks! You understood my problem exactly and I tried your proposed solution but did not work Here is my sample code.

Comment: I have edited my original question with sample code I tested. Any help in pointing out what Im doing incorrectly will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I edited my answer above to reflect the changes in your code.  Looks like you used the <div> id, whereas what you really needed was to use the class (or probably better would be an ID) of the <ul> tag.